# Apache mod_rewrite remove a folder in url and php extension

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite

**Hey,**

**I am trying to make my url a bit prettier with apache mod_rewrite.**

- html (root)

  - css
  - js
  - layout
  - sites (folder)

    - profil.php
    - work.php
  - index.php

**At the moment my url looks like this:**

https://example.com/sites/profil.php

https://example.com/sites/work.php

**And I want that it looks like this:**

https://example.com/profil

https://example.com/work

How can I can I **overwrite the "sites folder"** so, **there is none** and is it possible to **remove the .php extension**?

Thats how my apache config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost example.com>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
<Directory "/var/www/example.com/html">
allow from all
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

*Do I need to edit my links after that change in my files?*

Answer (score 0):

Here are your mod rewrite rules

```
# Rewrite --- https://example.com/sites/profil.php => https://example.com/profil
RewriteRule ^profil$ sites/profil\.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite --- https://example.com/sites/work.php => https://example.com/work
RewriteRule ^work$ sites/work\.php [NC,L]
```

enter this into your `.htaccess` in the right location and give it a try.

Comment: I did it in my apache example.conf and it is not working. Do I have to edit my links in my index.php?

Comment: you should edit your links to this link https://example.com/profil - the newly created directories. have you restarted your apache web server?

Comment: If I put this in my link: <a href="work">WORK</a> it is not working both of your examples. And yes I restarted my apache. The requested URL /work was not found on this server.

Comment: its example.com/work not work, what happens when you go to the browser and enter example.com/work/ ?

Comment: Then it puts a second example in the url https://example.com/example.com/work. <a href="example.com/work">WORK</a>. In Browser example.com/work url not found.

Comment: can you share your httpd.conf section where you are entering these rules. you may have placed it in the wrong place.

Comment: I put a github link in my config anwser to get a better overview of the project. I have put it in the example.conf from apache not in the httpd.conf

Comment: @c00L sorry for the confusion. try the rule again, i have updated the answer.

Comment: It is not easy :) Now, I updated restarted and it is still not working. Following link: '<a href="https://example.com/work/">Work</a>'

Comment: the href should be href="work" - what happens when you try http://example.com/work/ in the browser now?

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /work was not found on this server.
It is really not easy. Thanks for your help. Apruchiate it :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost example.com>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
<Directory "/var/www/example.com/html">
allow from all
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^sites/profil\.php$ /profil?&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^sites/work\.php$ /work?&%{QUERY_STRING}
</VirtualHost>
```